# how to get result of search without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, search

i want to do live search without refreshing the whole page.i am new in ajax jquery.see this image

[image]

when we click on search button  i want to filter the results based on that without refreshing the whole page with all those required parameters chosen by sql query through PHP MySQL with AJAX Jquery, how to do this with ajax,php,mysql..

this is html code of search panel:-

```
 <form id="frmSearch" method="post">
            <table width="850px" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:11px;font-weight:bold">
            <tr>
            <td width="80px">I Want to</td>
            <td width="140px">Property Type</td>
            <td>Budget</td>
            <td>Bedrooms</td>
            <td>Location</td>
            </tr>


         <tr>
             <td width="80px"><select name="want-to" class="tb112" style="height: 20px; width:80px;">
                    <option value="0">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">Buy</option>
                    <option value="2">Rent</option>
                  </select>                </td>
                <td width="140px"><select id="propertyType" class="tb112" onchange="PropertyTypeSelectChanged()"    style="height: 22px; width:160px;"          name="propertyType"   >
                  <option selected="selected" value="-1"> ---Select--- </option>
                  <optgroup label="ALL RESIDENTIAL"></optgroup>
                  <option value=" 1">Multistorey Apartment</option>
                  <option value="2">Builder Floor Apartment</option>
                  <option value="3">Residential House</option>
                  <option value="4">Villa</option>
                  <option value="5">Residential Plot</option>
                  <option value="6">Penthouse</option>
                  <option value=" 7">Studio Apartment</option>
                  <option value="8">Service Apartment</option>
                  <option value=" 9">Holiday Home</option>
                  <optgroup label="ALL COMMERCIAL"></optgroup>
                  <option value="10">Commercial Office Space</option>
                  <option value=" 11">Office in IT Park/ SEZ</option>
                  <option value=" 12">Commercial Shop</option>
                  <option value=" 13">Space in Shopping Mall</option>
                  <option value=" 14">Commercial Showroom</option>
                  <option value=" 15">Kiosk</option>
                  <option value=" 16">Business Centre</option>
                  <option value=" 17">Commercial Land</option>
                  <option value=" 18">Warehouse/ Godown</option>
                  <option value=" 19">Guest House</option>
                  <option value="20">Hotel</option>
                  <option value="21">Hotel Sites</option>
                  <option value=" 22">Industrial Land</option>
                  <option value="23">Industrial Building</option>
                  <option value=" 24">Industrial Shed</option>
                  <optgroup label="ALL AGRICULTURAL"></optgroup>
                  <option value=" 25">Agricultural Land</option>
                  <option value=" 26">Farm House</option>
                </select></td>
                <td width="110px">
                    <select name="select" id="select1" class="tb112" style=" Height:20px; width:100px;">
                      <option value="-1">Min</option>
                      <option class="" value="1">Below 5 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="500000">5 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="1000000">10 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="1500000">15 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="2000000">20 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="2500000">25 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="3000000">30 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="4000000">40 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="5000000">50 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="6000000">60 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="7500000">75 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="9000000">90 Lacs</option>
                      <option class="" value="10000000">1 Crore</option>
                      <option class="" value="15000000">1.5 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="20000000">2 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="30000000">3 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="50000000">5 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="100000000">10 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="200000000">20 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="300000000">30 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="400000000">40 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="500000000">50 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="600000000">60 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="700000000">70 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="800000000">80 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="900000000">90 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="1000000000">100 Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="28">100+ Crores</option>
                      <option class="" value="99">On Request</option>
                    </select></td>
                <td width="110px"><select name="select3" class="tb112" id="select3" style=" Height:20px; width:100px;">
                    <option value="-1">Max</option>
                    <option class="" value="1">Below 5 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="500000">5 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="1000000">10 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="1500000">15 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="2000000">20 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="2500000">25 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="3000000">30 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="4000000">40 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="5000000">50 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="6000000">60 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="7500000">75 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="9000000">90 Lacs</option>
                    <option class="" value="10000000">1 Crore</option>
                    <option class="" value="15000000">1.5 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="20000000">2 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="30000000">3 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="50000000">5 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="100000000">10 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="200000000">20 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="300000000">30 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="400000000">40 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="500000000">50 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="600000000">60 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="700000000">70 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="800000000">80 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="900000000">90 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="1000000000">100 Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="28">100+ Crores</option>
                    <option class="" value="99">On Request</option>
                  </select>                </td>
                <td width="100px">      <select name="BedRooms" class="tb112" style="height: 20px; width:90%;">
                          <optgroup label="Numbers Of Bedrroms" disabled="disabled"></optgroup>
                          <option class="" value="-1">--Select--</option>
                          <option class="" value="1">1</option>
                          <option class="" value="2"> 2</option>
                          <option class="" value="3">3</option>
                          <option class="" value="4">4</option>
                          <option class="" value="5">5</option>
                          <option class="" value="6">6</option>
                          <option class="" value="7">7</option>
                          <option class="" value="8">8</option>
                          <option class="" value="9">9</option>
                          <option class="" value="10">9+</option>
                        </select>                </td>

                <td>
                    <select name="city1" class="tb112" style="height: 20px; width:90%;">
                        <option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>
                        <option class="boldclass" value="12">Mumbai (All)</option>
                        <option class="" value="14">Central Mumbai suburbs</option>
                        <option class="" value="275">Mira Road And Beyond</option>
                        <option class="" value="218">Mumbai Andheri-Dahisar</option>
                        <option class="" value="274">Mumbai Beyond Thane</option>
                        <option class="" value="13">Mumbai Harbour</option>
                        <option class="" value="15">Mumbai Navi</option>
                        <option class="" value="18">Mumbai Others</option>
                        <option class="" value="16">Mumbai South</option>
                        <option class="" value="17">Mumbai South West</option>
                        <option class="" value="219">Mumbai Thane</option>
                  </select>             </td>
                    <td width="150px">
                    <input type="submit"  class="bgf"  value="Search" id="btnsearch" />             </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: I hope you know about Ajax.

Comment: If you need to update part of a page without reloading the whole page, you definitely need AJAX. There are quite a few things to learn. Why don't you check out the tutorial at w3schools.

Comment: i have idea about ajax.

Comment: i am finding on internet also but didnt get any proper code yet

Comment: Refer this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Don't try to find a code. Try to learn, then you will definitely get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach. However its just a rough description, you will have to put your effort. As you said you have an idea AJAX, so you can understand this. For more AJAX details go to w3schools.

1. Call a javaScript function whenever user hits submit button of the
   form. For Example:

   < button id ="Search" class="Style"  onclick="Search()">Search < /button>
2. Write your javascript function such that you can get the values of
   all the fields. For example:

   var s = document.getElementById("IDWillGoHere").value;
3. Once you get the value, use AJAX to communicate with server side
   script and send all variables. For example:

   object.send ("identifier=search&var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2+"&var3="+var3);

   Here identifier is assumed variable to tell server the type of information being sent.
   It is optional. It is required if you are sending request to php page with many
   response scripts.
4. On the server side you can write script to fetch the variables sent
   through AJAX. For example:

   ```
   if ($_POST['identifier']=="search" )
   ```

   {

   Sanitize and authenticate the variables.

   Perform database operations (SQL,NOSQL, etc) to fetch required information.

   Now suppose you get several variables as a result v1,v2,v3,v4........ etc, make a single variable out of those with your personal defined separator (may be ~, @, etc), for example:

   $output = v1."~".v2."~".v3 ......... and so on;

   Then use json to encode and sent it to client side. For example:

   echo json_encode ("$output");

   exit();

   }
5. Receive the sent data from server side script through AJAX. For
   example:

   var r = eval("(" + object.responseText + ")"); // this will decode the json encoded
   server side output.
6. Then split the received variable according to your defined seperator
   (here its ~). For example:

   var rs=r.split("~");
7. Now as you know how many variables was sent by server side script,
   so you can get all of them. For Example:

   var v1=rs[0];
   var v2=rs[1]; and so on
8. Then display the variables v1, v2, etc accordingly. For example:

   document.getElementById('IDWillGoHere').innerHTML="var1";

Comment: Forgot to mention, try to send and receive minimum information for faster loading :).